# xamarin c# iOS webrequest 401 error

Tags: c#, xamarin, webrequest

i wrote one Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://192.168.11.7:443/areas");
    // WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8888", false);
    // request.Proxy = myproxy;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("111", "123456");

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string JsonAreas = responseFromServer;
    txt1.Text = JsonAreas;
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
    return true;
}
```

If I debug this in my WindowsForms Application I have no Problems.

If I debug this in my iOS Application i get 401 error.

So i found out, iOS dont sent the Authorization Header.

I tried to catch the information with Fiddler, so you can see the Problem and help me ?
What I need to add manually to the header ?

Maybe I need to check the first answer and send it back ?

Thats what the Windows Forms is sending, i cant catch the iOS with Fiddler:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: Digest authentication is not secure at all. But if you insist, you might check out https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19759/xamarin-and-digest-authentication

Comment: Thats whats the Windows Forms App do automatically...whats the better way ?